# Как через рефлексию добавить метод к сетеру?

Tags: c#, события, рефлексия, делегаты, property

Например: есть свойство `public int PropertyName { get; private set; }` Как через рефлексию добавить метод в `set`? Конкретно нужно вызвать в нем событие которое находится в этом же классе.

Comment: а почему при описании свойства сразу не добавить?

Comment: Возможно копать [туда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3645436/12888024)

Comment: @Grundy Думаю это чужой код и он не сможет изменить класс. Вот и прибегает к черной магии

Comment: @AzizUmarov, как вариант, но тогда может спасти декоратор, через который работать с нужным классом